# How to create a curve plot (soft line chart) using Plotly python

Tags: plotly, customization, linechart, figure

I'm looking to build a line chart similar to the below one but I can't find a way to make the line "soft";

I tried to find a similar chart in Plotly but I didn't find it

[image]

I tried to find a similar chart in Plotly docs but I didn't find it;

There is a way to reproduce this chart using Plotly Express or graph_objects?

Thank you in advance,

Regards,
Leonardo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use a `spline` to achieve what you want by passing the argument `line_shape='spline'` to `go.Figure` (described briefly in the [interpolation with line plots](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#interpolation-with-line-plots) section in the plotly documentation)

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
y = np.array([10, 30, 20, 50, 70])

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, line_shape='spline'))
fig.show()
```

[image]